# using delimiter "|" is not working as expected when turning dataframe into csv

Tags: dataframe, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, delimiter

I have writen out dataframe using delimter ,. It creates a csv with separate columns but when use the "delimiter" "|" like in the below code it does not separate columns.

```
df.write.option("header", True).option("delimiter", "|").mode("overwrite").csv(tax_output)
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Can you add an example of what you see in the output file?

Answer (score 0):

Try `.options(delimiter="|")` or `.option("sep", "|")`